# stuck into building jar with external jar dependency

Tags: java, jar, manifest, executable-jar

I'm trying to build a executable jar only using the terminal with the following directory structure:

```
project-folder
|---lib
|   |---commons-io-2.6.jar
|---src
|   |---App.java
|   |---App.class
|   |---App$1.class
|   |---App$2.class
|---manifest.mf
|---App.jar
```

How you can see I have already created the App.jar with the command:

```
jar cmf manifest.mf App.jar src/*.class
```

But when I try to execute the App.jar file with

```
java -jar App.jar
```

I get the error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: App (wrong name: src/App)

Here is my manifest.mf:

```
Class-Path: lib/commons-io-2.6.jar
Main-Class: src/App
```

Can't see where the fault is and still searching for hours..
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the compiler is trying to tell you that it has a package srcApp;. You need to run it from the package root on.

Comment: So u mean I should use: `jar cmf ../manifest.mf ../App.jar *.class ../lib/commons-io-2.6.jar` and execute it from src folder?

Comment: Or can I also leave `../lib/commons-io-2.6.jar` out cause I have it already in manifest file (Class-Path)?